# Most efficient way to check if boolean key exists and include it in if statement

Tags: javascript

Here are two objects:

```
var user1 = { test: true }
var user2 = { nope : "noper" }
var user3 = { test: false }
```

I want to check if test is true across all three objects. Is this the most effective way to do it? (Assume I have 100k + objects)

```
var users = [user1, user2, user3]
var users_length = users.length
for(var i = 0; i < users_length; i++)
    if(("test" in users[i]) && users[i].test) { //evals to true }
```

Comment: Why can't you use `if (user1.test && user2.test)`? Are you anticipating more than two objects?

Comment: @Andy if I'm caching the length I would think so.

Comment: Your question makes less sense now you've edited it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Array.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) which returns true if and only if the function parameter returns true for all the array elements.

```js
var user1 = { test: true }
var user2 = { nope: "noper" }
var users = [user1, user2]

var result = users.every( function( user ) {
    return user.test;
});

console.log( result );
```

Although if you always have only two objects then `user1.test && user2.test` is much simpler.

(Note that `"test" in users[i] && users[i].test` is redundant because if the element `test` doesn't exist then `users[i].test` will be falsey (undefined).)

Comment: Unless you have several thousand objects and you're iterating through them several thousand times then the difference is likely to be somewhere around fractions of a millisecond.

Comment: Note that if you are using IE this will only work in IE9 or later: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every

Comment: Out of interest why would some user objects not have the test property? Why wouldn't they have the property but it be set to false?

Comment: Maybe they didn't take an action where the property was set and the property isn't needed but for very specific cases.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would do something simple like this:

```
var user1 = { test: true }
var user2 = { nope : "noper" }
var user3 = { test: false }

var users = [user1, user2, user3]
var result = true;

for(var i = 0, j = users.length; i < j; i++){
    result = result && !!users[i].test
    if (!result){
        break;
    }
}

alert(result);
```

(This assumes that you want to return a false if the property "test" is not present on the object)

This caches the length of the array so it is not computed every the loops executes and then breaks when a false is encountered as there is no point continuing if that is the case. This should give you better performance. The !! coerces the value of the test property into a boolean which is 'anded' to the result (not strictly needed due to the falsey check below it but I like to add it in so that the final result is a boolean).

http://jsfiddle.net/jkyftjpu/

Answer (score 0):

First of all, caching length is useless in any modern browser (except IE8). JITs easily cache it on their own.

Most effective code is:

```
for(var i = users.length-1; i; i--) { // Reversed iteration is little bit faster
    if((Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(users[i], 'test') && users[i].test) {
        // Your code goes here
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not client side, regardless, thanks for pointing to me .call - never used it before. I'm not too concerned about going up the prototype chain but I'll compare speed and mark correct if appropriate. Thanks!

Comment: Traversing prototype chain is **expensive**, this is a point.
For me, traversing 100k objects took 1.3s.

Not good. Why do you have so much objects?

Comment: And maybe asynchronous processing can prevent your application from blocking? https://github.com/caolan/async#every

Comment: I was reviewing some code I had written when I was just learning and was wondering the best way to do it. The 100k objects were for graphing and I hadn't done any appropriate scaling.